# ¿Por qué este switch case dentro de un do while se repite infinitamente?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer que en un `switch`/`case` se detecte si se ingresó una letra en vez de un número. Pero me da un error que al simplificar el código, se ve que se esta haciendo un loop infinito.

Comenté lo innecesario y dejé lo mas simple, pero por más que analizo el código no veo el por qué de que se repita infinitamente.

La función `validaropcion`, y todo lo que conlleva, la copié de la web, no sé si tenga algún error, no creo. De todas maneras tal y como está el código no debería afectar.

Éste es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int validaropcion(char y);

int validaropcion(char y){
    if(isalpha(y)){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n Solo ingrese numeros! ";
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }   
}

int main(){
    //char y;
    int opcion, x;
    cin>>opcion;
    /*if(isalpha(opcion)){
        do{
            char(opcion);
            y=opcion;
            x=(validaropcion(y));                               
        }while(x==0);   
    }
    else{*/
    do{
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                cout<<" bien";
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                cout<<" mal"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }while(opcion!=2);  
    //}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, fijate que dentro de tu bloque `do while` no estás modificando el valor de `opcion`, por lo tanto, siempre se evalúa el while con el mismo valor.

Comment: @MarioL , pero comparando este código a otros códigos que estoy haciendo, la estructura `do while` es igual, solo cambiaría lo que se declara dentro de cada case. Porque tendría que modificar opción? No se su pone que después de hacer el `case 1` vuelve al comienzo del `switch case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con un `do while` se crea un bucle que ejecuta un bloque de código específico, hasta que la condición de comprobación se evalúa como falsa. La condición se evalúa después de ejecutar el bloque, dando como resultado que el bloque de código se ejecute al menos una vez. Ahora, en tu código en particular, si al comienzo de la ejecución del ciclo `do while` tenemos que `opcion=1`, por ejemplo, se ejecutará el case 1 y se mostrará el mensaje "bien", pero luego nada más, a continuación se pasará a evaluar la condición del `while`. Aquí el valor de `opcion` sigue siendo 1, por lo tanto, la condición se cumple y se continuará ejecutando. Te dejo un ejemplo para que sea un poco más claro lo que ya puse en los comentarios:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

   int a = 15;


   do {
      cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
      a = a + 1; //Nuevo valor para la variable a ser evaluada
   } while( a < 20 );

   return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
value of a: 15
value of a: 16
value of a: 17
value of a: 18
value of a: 19
```

Si te fijas en este ejemplo, dentro del bucle `do while` tenemos la sentencia

```
a = a + 1;
```

de esta forma, se cambia el valor de la variable a ser evaluada en el while de la estructura, y con esto, el bucle terminará cuando la condición no se cumpla.

En resumen, tu bucle se ejecuta indefinidamente porque la condición siempre se cumple, es decir, `opcion!=2`. Si probás ingresando un valor de `opcion = 2` podrás comprobar que el bucle se ejecuta sólo una vez.

Comment: Pero como te digo estoy haciendo un código el cual hasta el momento tiene hasta tres `do while` anidados, y en todos ingreso la condicion `variable != int`, y no se repiten así. Con la opcion que me das "opcion = 2" solo se haría una vez, y lo que yo quiero es que se repita el menú hasta que ingresen el numero 2, que ahí si haría que se cerrara la aplicación. Y no se supone que el `break` se usa para evitar que suceda lo que me está sucediendo?

Comment: Mario, ya vi el error, cuando leo `opcion` lo hago fuera del `do`, y solo hay que colocar la línea de código dentro. Pero ahora me puedes ayudar con la parte de leer si es una letra? Porque si pongo la lectura de `opción` dentro del `do` no habría forma de realizar el primer if.

Comment: Puedes revisar esta respuesta en relación al tema de controlar si se ingresa una letra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616867/how-to-test-a-string-for-letters-only. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que solicitas una única vez el valor de `opcion` y luego en el bucle no vuelves a solicitarlo, por lo que siempre tendrá el mismo valor.

Te recomiendo mover el `cin` al interior del bucle:

```
int main(){
    int opcion, x;
    do{
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                cout<<" bien";
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                cout<<" mal"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }while(opcion!=2);  
    //}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A parte de no tener el `std::cin()` dentro del bucle como [te indican en esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/196351/18608), otro problema grave que sufres es que no controlas si hubo un error obteniendo el valor entero de la entrada de datos.

Para comprobar si se introdujo correctamente un entero en la variable `opcion` o no hago uso de [`std::cin.good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/).

En caso de no haber sido un número entero devolverá un valor diferente de cero, por lo que deberemos borrar el código de error con [`std::cin.clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) y, posteriormente, sacar de la entrada estándar todo lo que hayamos introducido (que no pudo convertirse en entero) hasta el próximo retorno del carro con [`std::cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).

Aquí tienes tu código corregido:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int opcion, x;
    do {
        std::cout << "Introduzca una opción: ";
        /* Obtenemos el valor del teclado */
        std::cin >> opcion;
        /* Si algo no fue bien durante la obtención */
        if (!std::cin.good()) {
            std::cout << "no es un número" << std::endl;
            /* Borramos el indicador de error */
            std::cin.clear();
            /* Ignoramos lo que tecleamos */
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            /* Volvemos a repetir el bucle */
            continue;
        }
        /* Ahora ya podemos comprobar su contenido */
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "bien" << std::endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "mal" << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, espero aún te sirva.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
char y;
int opcion=1, x;

do{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\tIngrese un caracter: ";
    cin >> y;

    if(isalpha(y))
        cout << "\n\n\t\tHa ingresado una letra correctamente";
    else
        cout << "\n\n\t\tEl caracter ingresado no corresponde a una letra";

    cout << "\n\n\t\250Desea volver a intentar? (<Si: 1> <No: 2>): ";
    cin >> opcion;
}while(opcion==1);
            //}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No estaría de más incluir un texto explicando los motivos por los que el código de la pregunta falla y por qué tu propuesta soluciona su problema. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Es infinito porque al asignarle una letra o cualquier valor diferente de 2 a `opcion`, el bucle `do-while` siempre se repetirá ya que tu condición así lo afirma:

```
do {
    switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            cout<<" bien";
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            cout<<" mal"<<endl;
            break;
    }
    // En ninguna parte se cambió el valor de opción
    // Para que se detenga, debes cambiar el valor a 2 ya que la condición así lo afirma
} while(opcion != 2);
```